# What is the meaning of data_shape in CSVIter of MXNet

Tags: mxnet

if I have a input matrix of 400 rows with 20 features and I have 10 labels then what should be my data_shape and label_shape tuples

Answer (score 1):

Each row of your input CSV file can be viewed as a vector and it will be reshaped into the `data_shape`. So, if a row in an input file is 1,2,3,4,5,6 and data_shape is (3,2), that row will be reshaped, yielding the array [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] of shape (3,2).

You can see [CSVIter doc](http://mxnet.io/api/python/io.html#mxnet.io.CSVIter) for more details.